# Get all the gameobjects for a SceneManager scene in Unity

Tags: unity, scenemanager

I'm using the new SceneManager to load multiple scenes in the same structure adopting the Additive method. I find it extremely useful but I wonder if there is a way to get all the GameObjects for a specific scene. When multiple scenes are loaded I see the GameObjects clearly separated by scene in the hierarchy but I cannot find a way to access the specific hierarchy of a single scene via script. Is that possible? 
The findGameObject method I think returns the GameObjects for all the scenes..

Answer (score 4):

You can get all the root Game Objects of a specific scene using `SceneManagenent`, that will return an array of `GameObject`.

```
GameObject[] _rootGameObjectsOfSpecificScene = SceneManager.GetSceneByName("YOUR_SCENE_NAME").GetRootGameObjects();
```

Replace `YOUR_SCENE_NAME` with your scene name.

Comment: What version did this show up in? It doesn't appear to exist in 5.3.1.